# How to have a section start on an odd page _and_ number the page with a prefix starting again at 1?

Tags: adobe-indesign, book, layout, numbering, section-marker

I've set up a paragraph format `section`, which starts on the next odd page. Additionally, I would like the page number to be prefixed by the section number and starting again at 1, i.e. page numbers would be something like

```
1-1  # section 1
1-2
1-3
1-4  # might be an empty page automatically inserted
2-1  # section 2
2-2
3-1  # section 3
```

Unfortunately, when I set up the page number to start again at 1 (and set the prefix to the section number), the "start on next odd page" automatism basically breaks, since I "defined" the page to *be* odd, despite the physical page possibly being even, i.e. in the example above, the empty page `1-4` gets skipped and `2-1` directly follows after `1-3` unless I manually add an empty even page, which is tedious and I might actually forget to do so when appending to that section such that e.g. `1-5` is also added automatically.

How can this be fixed? Maybe there is an easer way to have (automatically?) prefixed page numbers while making sure `section`s start on *physically* odd pages?

Comment: I'm aware I could create an InDesign-Book with chapters, which could probably circumvent this, but the chapter/sections are quite short and having a separate file for each would really be overkill...

Answer (score 2):

I could not find an "automatic" method, but I did find a method that could help.

**Select the pages you want to define as one section.**

**Right-Click > Numbering and Section Options**

**In the "Section Marker" box (not "Section Prefix") type in "1 - "** (I added spaces before and after the hyphen).

**Repeat for each following section**, changing the "Section Marker" to the appropriate number. Make sure to select "Start Page Numbering at:" and change that to "1".

You should end up with:

**1 - 1 (Section Marker - Page Number)**

**1 - 2 (Section Marker - Page Number)**

**1 - 3 (Section Marker - Page Number)**

**1 - 4 (Section Marker - Page Number)**

*Repeat*

**2 - 1 (Section Marker - Page Number)**

**2 - 2 (Section Marker - Page Number)**

**2 - 3 (Section Marker - Page Number)**

**2 - 4 (Section Marker - Page Number)**

**ETC.**

If you notice your page layouts changing oddly, try clicking the fly-out menu at the top of your pages panel and uncheck "Allow Document Pages to Shuffle"and rearrange them back to their proper layout